# Reusing a LSTM cell in tensor flow

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I want to train many case with only one LSTM cell.

I tried like below and it give me an error like this `ValueError: Variable RNN/BasicLSTMCell/Linear/Matrix already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope? Originally defined at:`

I think this error is occurred because I tried to reuse LSTM cell.
I can't find the method to solve this error.

Someone saids using `get_variable()` function to reuse LSTM cell but I can't understand how to use it.
Below is my source code. How can I solve this problem

```
rnn_size = 2
time_step_size = 23
batch_size = 1


rnn_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_size)
state = rnn_cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)
for i in range(len(x_data)):
    x = process_x(x_data[i])[:23]
    y = word[i][:23]
    x_split = tf.split(0, time_step_size, x)
    outputs, state = tf.nn.rnn(rnn_cell, x_split, state)

    prediction = tf.reshape(tf.concat(1, outputs), [-1, rnn_size])
    real = tf.reshape(y, [-1])
    ratio = tf.ones([time_step_size * batch_size])

    loss = tf.nn.seq2seq.sequence_loss_by_example([prediction], [real], [ratio])
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(loss)/batch_size
    train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)

    # h_loss = tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)
    h_cost = tf.summary.scalar('cost', cost)
    merged = tf.summary.merge_all()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
        writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("../NLP_tensorboards/"+__file__.split('/')[-1], sess.graph)
        for step in range(10000):
            sess.run(train)
            summary = sess.run(merged)
            writer.add_summary(summary, step)
        result = sess.run(tf.arg_max(prediction, 1))
        # print [t for t in result] == word[gap:]
        # print ''.join([char_rdic[t] for t in result])
        # print result, word[gap:], x_data[gap:], x_data
        print result, [t for t in result] == y
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
```